# AdMob test ads shows only on English devices

Tags: android, admob

After I installed Google Play Services APIs 6.4.1 to insert banners in my app, i had hard times to make it work.

On my test device (nexus-S mounting JB 4.1.2, language set to Italian) i don't see any ads, with this logcat:

```
01-27 13:22:55.518: I/Ads(3463): Use AdRequest.Builder.addTestDevice("2CF3523D47F0CFC8A7523B041D9BB325") to get test ads on this device.
01-27 13:22:55.522: I/Ads(3463): Starting ad request.
01-27 13:23:43.998: I/Ads(3463): No fill from ad server.
01-27 13:23:44.409: W/Ads(3463): Failed to load ad: 3
```

When i run it on a JB 4.2.1 Nexus 7 with language set to English(us) it works until i change language (Settings->Language&input->Language) to Italian, then i cannot see ads anymore.

It looks like there are no ads for non-english languages, but this happens for both test and real ads.

Tried also with emulators, running GB 2.3.3 and JB 4.3, both display ads if language is set to English, both stop displaying ads if i change language.

Here's the code i use inside onCreate()

```
adView = (AdView)(view.findViewById(R.id.adView));
adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
    .addTestDevice("TEST_DEVICE_ID")
    .addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR)
    .addTestDevice("2CF3523D47F0CFC8A7523B041D9BB325") // nexus S
    .addTestDevice("9C75E9349CF38EF5EB2C6C6100E96A7E") // nexus 7
    .build();
adView.loadAd(adRequest);
```

How can i make admob work also on non-english devices?

Comment: You didn't mention your location. If you are in Italy then I think you are right there is a problem. But if you are not, there might not be any Italian ads to show.

Comment: @William i'm in Italy and i'm using both english and italian language for testing purpouses, this is the reason i realized the issue. Anyway when using english i can see both english and italian ads.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'm gonna answering myself, because it started working without any modification.

Ads have been displayed almost instantly for english devices, while, for some AdMob related reasons, to see ads in italian devices i had to wait for 4 (FOUR!!) days!

So, the answer is: just wait.

Hope this helps.