# Ads with AdMob and Google Play Services Library doesnt show on device

Tags: android, android-emulator, admob, device

I have a problem with AdMob and Google Play Services that is driving me crazy for days. It feels like it's practically impossible to make this work. What is wrong with this implementation?

layout.xml (the code below goes in the bottom of the layout):

```
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
...
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/layoutAd"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_weight="3"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
            android:id="@+id/adView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            ads:adSize="BANNER"
            ads:adUnitId="@string/ad_unit_id" />

    </LinearLayout>
```

MainActivity.java:

```
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdSize;

...
adView = (AdView)this.findViewById(R.id.adView);  
AdRequest request = new AdRequest.Builder() .addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR).
        addTestDevice("9234EBAE83E894E6271DEBE7B380782E").build();              
adView.loadAd(request);
```

AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
    ...
            <activity android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"
                android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"/>
```

LogCat:

```
Use AdRequest.Builder.addTestDevice("9234EBAE83E894E6271DEBE7B380782E") to get test ads on this device.

GooglePlayServicesUtil: The Google Play services resources were not found. Check your project configuration to ensure that the resources are included.

SQLiteLog: (14) cannot open file at line 30241 of [00bb9c9ce4]

SQLiteLog: (14) os_unix.c:30241: (2) open(/NotificationPermissions.db) -
```

The Ad never shows up but if I run it on the emulator, it does.

What am I dong wrong?

Comment: This is the same problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21382029/admob-test-ads-shows-only-on-english-devices .... maybe, it can help!

Answer (score 0):

Try reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19721158/utilize-both-play-services-and-admob-sdk) and [this](https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/admob/play-migration?hl=it)... `;)`

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion Comment the code

addTestDevice("9234EBAE83E894E6271DEBE7B380782E").build();

and connect your mobile , make sure computer detects your phone
and run the project, your device should appears on the select device to run
Click ok

Hope this helpe

Final suggestion, if you using Eclipse, goto Project in top menu click on 
many time this cleans junk data in workspace

Answer (score -3):

Try using:

```
import com.google.android.gms.ads.*;
```

Instead of:

```
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdSize;
```

This fixed some issues for me.