# AdMob test ads don't show ads but english devices

Tags: android, admob, ads

After solving "not enough space to show ad" problem, I'm facing another problem testing banner ads.
Ads just don't appear unless I set english language to my device, logcat shows this:

`Starting ad request.
No fill from ad server.
Failed to load ad: 3`

Yes, I came here reading another question with same problem, the guy answered himself saying that waited 4 days untill got test ads in his language.
[AdMob test ads shows only on English devices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21382029/admob-test-ads-shows-only-on-english-devices)

The real question here is: this problem will happen again when I stop testing ads? (in some different words, when I release my app to google play?) or is this just a TestDevice bug and I don't have to worry about it?

Thanks for reading!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will start getting ad fill for the language defined on the device as and when it is available. So short answer is that this is just a testing issue.

Long answer is that depending on ad inventory there may be limited ads in a particular language/location at any point in time. That is why it is always a good idea to use mediation so that if no fill is available you ask another ad network for fill.

Comment: using the native express ad examples on github, the ads show for the pub id in the example, but nothing shows for my pub id created on admob console. What could be the cause of this?